# Como listar arquivos em um diretório e usar em um projeto Angular2 + Webpack

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, fs

Olá, estou criando um projeto em Angular2 + Webpack e nesse projeto eu uso como biblioteca de design o `@angular/material`. Para que eu possa criar meus próprios ícones, usando SVG, eu estou extendendo o componente `MatIcon` [como diz na documentação](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api), e estou salvando meus SVG em um diretório acessível da aplicação. A estrutura do projeto está dessa forma:

```
- src
| - app
  | my-icon.component.ts
| - assets
  | - svg
    | - facebook.svg
    | - google.svg
    | - twitter.svg
```

Meu componente está da seguinte forma:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { MatIconRegistry } from "@angular/material";

export const icons = ["google", "facebook", "twitter"];

@Component({
  selector: "my-icon",
  template: `<mat-icon [svgIcon]="icon"></mat-icon>`
})
export class MyIcon {
  @Input() icon: string;

  constructor(i: MatIconRegistry, s: DomSanitizer) {
    for (let icon of icons)
      i.addSvgIcon(icon, s.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`assets/svg/${icon}.svg`));
  }
}
```

Meu problema é que toda vez que crio um novo SVG que seria um icon eu sou obrigado a vir no meu componente e atualizar minha constante `icons` com o nome do SVG.

Existe alguma forma de eu conseguir ler todos os arquivos da pasta "assets/svg" e já inserir na minha minha constante? Eu até vi que é possível fazer usando o **fs** do NodeJS como pode ser visto [nesse link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049557/reading-all-files-in-a-directory-store-them-in-objects-and-send-the-object) mas quando tento acessar o **fs** de dentro do meu componente, não retorno nenhuma informação.

Como resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Fiz uma pergunta semelhante há um tempo atrás*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/251890), e baseado no que encontrei, você pode utilizar o [Chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) informando o diretório, o caractere coringa seguido da extensão.

```
let watcher = chokidar.watch('assets/svg/*.svg');
```

observe o evento `add` sempre que um arquivo SVG for criado, colado ou movido para o diretório `assets/svg/` você pode executar uma ação:

```
watcher.on('add', (path, stats) => {
    icons.push(path);
});
```

[image: Veja funcionando]

#### Código do exemplo acima:

```
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
let icons = [];
let watcher = chokidar.watch('assets/svg/*.svg');
watcher.on('add', (path, stats) => {
    icons.push(path);
    show();
});
const show = _ => console.log(JSON.stringify(icons, null, 2));
```

Comment: excelente! se desse pra dar mais de 1 ponto eu dava! fantástico